# Measure of a closed set

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces, weak-convergence

I am reading Chapter 1 Section 1 in Patrick Billingsley (1999) "Convergence of probability measures" which deals with weak convergence in metric spaces and trying to understand the proof of this theorem.

> **Theorem 1.2.** Let $(S,\rho)$ be a metric space and $\mathcal{S}$ the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Probability measures $P$ and $Q$ on $\mathcal{S}$ coincide if $Pf=Qf$ for all bounded, uniformly continuous real functions $f$.
>
> **Proof.**
> Let $f=(1-\rho(x,F)/\epsilon)^+$. Then
> $\mathbf{1}_{F}(x) \leq f(x) \leq \mathbf{1}_{F^\epsilon}(x),$ where $\mathbf{1}_{F}$ is the indicator function on $F$ and $F^\epsilon$ is the $\epsilon$-neighbourhood of $F$. Then $f$ is bounded and uniformly continuous and
> $PF\leq Pf=Qf\leq QF^\epsilon$. Letting $\epsilon \downarrow 0$ gives $PF\leq QF$, provided $F$ is closed. By symmetry and since $P$ and $Q$ are regular, $P=Q$.

**Question**
What goes wrong if $F$ is not closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$F^{1/n}$ decreases to $F$ if $F$ is closed. In general it decreases to $\overline F$ so you only get $PF\leq Q \overline F$.

Comment: thank you. so the problem arise if $Q\partial F>0$ if $F$ is not closed, is this correct?

Comment: @12345 Yes, that is correct.

Comment: thank you @geetha290krm